# camlp4 : there is no quotation expander available

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

The file `test.ml` contains only one line:

```
let foo = <:expr< foo >>
```

I then apply camlp4 to that file with this command line:

```
camlp4o pa_extend.cmo test.ml
```

The output is:

```
File "test.ml", line 1, characters 12-24:
While finding quotation "expr" in a position of "expr":
  There is no quotation expander available.
  Camlp4: Uncaught exception: Not_found
```

I expected the file to be pre-processed and the quotation to be expanded appropriately. What am I forgetting here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ocaml >= 3.10, you should not use `pa_extend.cmo` but the new quotations modules. They are packed in the `camlp4of` executable that you can use directly instead of `camlp4` (or `camlp4rf` for revised syntax).